# View sources of sun.* packages in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to be able to step through the code in sun.* packages when I do debug in Eclipse. Unfortunately the source code for these packages is not included in Oracle JDK.

I found a decompiler plugin for Eclipse that allowed me to do it, but the lines of code Eclipse debugger was pointing to didn't match the decompiled code.

I'm using Windows and Java 8 (earlier versions won't work for me).

Comment: In the Java installation directory (e. g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`) there is a ZIP file `src.zip`. You have to add the missing source files into this ZIP archive.

Comment: @howlger And where do I get these missing source files for Oracle JDK?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the source files from the [OpenJDK repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun)
2. In the Java installation directory, add the downloaded source files to the `src.zip` archive

Comment: It didn't work. I was able to see the source in Eclipse but the line numbers didn't match. I guess there's a mismatch between the OpenJDK repository and the current Oracle JDK. I ended up just downloading full OpenJDK from https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases